# No puedo compilar mi código usando usando winsock

Tags: c++, socket

Me salen los siguientes errores de compilacion

```
SinNombre1.cpp:(.text+0x121): 
undefined reference to `__imp_getaddrinfo'

SinNombre1.cpp:(.text+0x263): 
undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo'

SinNombre1.cpp  [Warning] deprecated 
conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar `winsock` tienes que compilar con el flag `-lWs2_32`. De lo contrario la libreria de sockets no se carga y el compilador no puede enlazar correctamente el programa (no encuentra las funciones propias de los sockets).

El último mensaje que muestras es un aviso de que estás convirtiendo directamente de `std::string const` a `char*` y esa conversión está marcada como obsoleta... para darte alguna solución al respecto es recomendable que edites la pregunta e incluyas el código correspondiente.